# Is it a good idea to change/add keywords to an already well-ranking page?

Tags: seo, keywords

I have a site that is ranking bottom of page 1 for "IT support company" - however, I have since realised there are other keywords I could be ranking for as well, such as "IT support services," had I started off with a more long-tail keyword such as "IT support services company."

My question is, what results has anyone seen who has ever tinkered with a well-ranking page to try to add in another keyword?

I'm nervous that if I make any changes to the page title, for example, then I might drop for the first keyword and never recover! Or would restoring things if that happened eventually cause it to recover?

Any advice at all on adding new keywords to a well-ranking page or transitioning would be very much appreciated!

Comment: To add new keyword and do not remove existing will not damage current page position I think...

Comment: OK, but in the example I gave, I would have to add "services" into "IT support company," which would be modifying the existing keyword. If I wish to optimise the whole page for additional keywords, they will most likely need to be represented in the h1 and the page title as well, which risks changing how Google perceives the page...

Comment: Before you get carried away, you should read this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81551/why-would-a-website-with-keyword-stuffing-rank-higher-than-one-without-in-google/81552#81552 (ignore the title) This answer will help you with background knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, it was an interesting read. That said, I'm still not sure what the correct answer is here! :) I mean SEOs or otherwise still "target" certain keywords - some more successfully than others - so whether it's via stuffing (not in my case) or making subtle changes to meta tags or anchor text, I suppose I'm just looking to hear from someone who's experimented with this to see how their results turned out.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a site that is ranking bottom of page 1 for "IT support company" - however, I have since realised there are other keywords I could be ranking for as well, such as "IT support services," had I started off with a more long-tail keyword such as "IT support services company."

This is where planning and evaluating needs to take place.

You say you're ranking at the bottom for "IT support company". I'm assuming that's your title. Remember, the rank is mostly based on your title, meta description, words in H1 and H2 tags, and especially the queries people use.

What you should do is register your domain with Google Webmaster Tools and go to the search analytics section. In their older interface, there will be several columns.

One column lists the words people search, another column lists impressions, and another lists clicks as well as average search position.

Impressions means visitors saw your webpage in the search results when they searched for that specific term. clicks mean they accessed your site by clicking a search result.

If you want to rank high, look for search terms with a very high impression count and a very low click count. Next, try to adjust your title and meta description of your site to include the terms in exact order if possible.

So if you see in analytics that theres a high impression count for "IT services" and hardly any clicks for it, then change your title so the words "IT services" are included. If you want the word support added, then change it to "IT services plus support" or something like that.

> My question is, what results has anyone seen who has ever tinkered with a well-ranking page to try to add in another keyword?

I tinker with keywords as often as necessary and when I change my keywords to common words people use more often, I get more clicks into my page.

> I'm nervous that if I make any changes to the page title, for example, then I might drop for the first keyword and never recover! Or would restoring things if that happened eventually cause it to recover?

If you select a title that does not make sense or you select a title that doesn't fit with the content of your page, then expect rankings to drop. I can't see reverting back to the old title help you much. Your best friend is Google Webmaster Tools search analytics section. It can tell you what people search for in a time period and you can change that time period to understand search trends in relation to your site. It may be possible that in the last three days no one wanted to search for IT services or support.

Answer (score 0):

You are in a position to take a risk or not. As your webpage is already in 1st page so you can add new keywords to your webpage and it will surely help you to lift your page up.

Comment: Care to explain why this is true? Otherwise it sounds like an opinion to me.

Answer (score 0):

Keyword research is an SEO essential. You're looking for the best keywords-combination to raise in PageRank. Do some research on what are the best keywords with following tools, then decide:

- [Google Keyword planner](https://adwords.google.com/keywordplanner)
- [Google trends](https://www.google.com/trends/)
- [Bing Intelligence](http://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/bing-ads-intelligence)

And [here](http://backlinko.com/keyword-research)'s a nice article you'll want to read. Good luck.

Comment: This doesn't answer their question

Comment: If the OP does research concerning "IT support company" - "IT support services" with the tools provided, OP can search the answer himself. Keyword research is an art in itself, I provided some tools to help. Maybe I didn't answer the question solid but I hope I provided a valuable contribution worth something more than a comment.