# inverse actions and synonyms

Tags: google, search-results

I'm trying to figure out whether its worth adding copy in my pages that matches the related actions and synonyms of what the page is about.

For example I want my page to appear for people buying apartments ie typing "buy apartment in ...." or "buy apt in ...." currently the page has a lot of copy in the form of "apartment for sale in ...." and Google does a good job of showing the page (around 5 or 6th place).

I'm wondering if its worth including the exact phrase in the copy somewhere to improve my ranking and cover my bases so to speak.

In general my question is if exact matches for synonyms and related actions rank better, and if its worth me putting effort in trying to add copy for this.

Cheers

Simon

Answer (score -1):

I would argue that you should aim for a keyword density of 3-4% on the page. If achieving this goes with what you've asked then I would do it. If you're already in that sweet spot then I don't think it'd matter, and may harm the site in the long run.

Comment: You need to read this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81551/why-would-a-website-with-keyword-stuffing-rank-higher-than-one-without-in-google/81552#81552 It dispels the keyword density myth once and for all. Time to put another nail in the coffin of this craziness.

Comment: To be honest I think SEO is total snake oil anyway. If the content is good, easy to read, and is about what it's meant to be about, then the page will score high.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head!! Yes there are signals to send, but the best thing to do is be natural and let the content speak for itself. You do have to craft the title tag, h1 tag, and description meta-tag for CTR. Other than that, search is mostly semantics based now days. It still pays to understand how search engines work. As for snake oil, I agree that 99% of all SEO advice is pure BULL Squirt. Where it pays to be attentive is applying an understanding of search in simple easy disciplines. I spend a lot of time correcting the SEO record here. I hate the SEO BS. Drives me nuts!