# Does single focus keyword include other site information?

Tags: seo, keywords

Lets say I have a website for a campground in Texas and am trying to search engine optimize it so potential customers can easily find my site on Google.

I have a series of other pages that have SEO focusing on the campgrounds name and its location.

I then decide to add a reviews page that has a bunch of nice reviews. I set the focus keyword to 'Reviews' (using Yoast-SEO plugin for Wordpress)

What happens when somebody searches on Google my campgrounds name followed by reviews?

-Does Google know that this reviews page is from this campgrounds website and therefore shows up high on results?

-Or will the focus keyword 'Reviews' only be optimize for that word and be lost a million pages deep for the keyword 'Reviews'?

Comment: None of the above. That's going to make very little difference on that page's rankings.

Comment: @JohnConde Does Google know that 'reviews' are related to the campground though?

Are you saying to choose a different Focus Keyword then?

Comment: You will want to read this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81551/why-would-a-website-with-keyword-stuffing-rank-higher-than-one-without-in-google/81552#81552 It explains a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> If <15% of the rankings equation is wrapped up in keyword targeting,...

coming from SEO people:  https://moz.com/blog/visual-guide-to-keyword-targeting-onpage-optimization if you are a visual person.

Present unique information / content that generates traffic is more valuable than keyword placement.  John Conde is right.  In the past people have overloaded pages with "keywords" to get higher search rankings.  Because of that, the search engines have altered their criteria.  Just give information that is unique and informative about the campgrounds that other campsite-reviews.com would not have.  Or pay money to a dirty SEO company for hundreds of non-legitimate backlinks and risk Google slapping your hand.  Bad, bad website, no page rank for you.

Comment: I read through the link and agree with what was said. I was underestimating the mighty powerhouse that is Google and focusing to much on my keyword. Thanks for those who answered I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> I then decide to add a reviews page that has a bunch of nice reviews. I set the focus keyword to 'Reviews' (using Yoast-SEO plugin for Wordpress)

What you want to do is make a focus phrase " campsite reviews" instead of just "reviews". You may need a different plugin if Yoast-SEO won't allow phrases as the focus instead of individual keywords.

> What happens when somebody searches on Google my campgrounds name followed by reviews?

If the TTFB (time to first byte) of your page is under 200 milliseconds and the content is excellent and the top keywords are `<insert business name here> reviews` together in that order spread nicely throughout the page, then that someone could see your page as showing up first, unless someone bought ad space from google about your topic, in which case, they will appear first in the search results.

Google Webmaster tools is your best friend. Visit it and add your website and four days later, visit their search analytics section to see what people search for in order to find your site in the results. That will give you a better idea of what keywords you should use and what order to use them if you want your site to appear near the top of the search results. A higher impression count for a phrase in search analytics means more people are interested in that phrase and that phrase is what you should try to go for then on your site, you can have a common section with a link to reviews so the searcher can still access them.

> -Does Google know that this reviews page is from this campgrounds website and therefore shows up high on results?

If the exact phrase `<insert business name here> reviews` appears 2% to 5% of the time in the page in the important places such as header tags, then it might rank well, however, google evaluates other websites to see how they fit compared to yours to determine which appears first.

> -Or will the focus keyword 'Reviews' only be optimize for that word and be lost a million pages deep for the keyword 'Reviews'?

Trying to optimize for the word reviews by itself is like trying to be better than millions of pages because that word is so common where as `<insert business name here> reviews` is less common.

Nevertheless, think about what people want from your site, not what you want to boast about (such as reviews). Try going for phrases like `lower priced campsites at <insert business name here>` or maybe `unique adventures at <insert business name here>`

And in my answer, replace text in `< >` with the name of your business, and try to keep the phrases short as using longer phrases will require a higher word count on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Research the keyword vertical for **reviews** AND **camp ground**, find out extra "operator" words used most commonly in conjunction with these two concepts. A simple example being "top" or "best". Once you have used a longtail keyword discovery tool, (clevergizomos) i would recommend or scrapebox.

Then start to include these words in the copy of your text and you will naturally start to make the page contextually relevant to searchers related to reviews and campgrounds, separating it and unique-ifying it so it can rank independently and not be competing with your other pages.