# Is having a keyword appear twice in the URL good?

Tags: seo, url-parameters, keyword-stuffing, url-keywords

Let's say the keyword i am targeting is "JavaScript" for seo of my website And My domain name is JavaScript.com. Now i post a blog something like "What is the scope of variables in JavaScript". So my url becomes:

`www.javascript.com/blog/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript`

Notice that JavaScript keyword is repeated twice in the URL. My question is, will it be good or bad to have targeted keyword more than once in the URL itself.? Will google consider it as keyword stuffing.

Comment: You are okay. The example you have given is quite normal and your right to do. No worries!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, please stop thinking in terms of keywords. I assure you that Google does not match keywords. The process is far more sophisticated than simply seeing if a term exists. In fact, term matches are not done. Semantic topic matches are however. So stop thinking in terms of keywords. It is a waste. Think topic.

The URL can be divided into 4 basic parts; the protocol and domain name, the path, the file name, and parameters. The order of importance is from left to right; domain name, path, file, and parameters with significant weight given to the domain name and path as better long standing indications of what a web page is about far more than the file name and parameters. In fact, the domain name and path along with inbound links are the highest value semantic clues you can give to any page followed by the h1 tag and description meta-tag. Keep this in mind.

Each part is evaluated semantically for value. Using your example, javascript.com, would yield topical scores for javascript and potenially java and script in that order of value. Your path, /what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript/, would not only yield javascript, java, and script but also variable, and scope.

Semantics is about understanding what is written and creates algorithmic score matrices by terms and various other syntactic structures that allows the content elements to understood. At the very least, this allows subject, predicate, and object relationships to be understood. For example, Bob threw the ball. would indicate that the subject Bob, threw (predicate), ball (object). In your case, *what is*, *scope of variables*, and *variables in javascript* are your strongest semantic clues within the path.

The combined semantic matrices for your domain name along with your path make javascript and potentially java and script score highest.

Before you begin to think that you should also load keywords into a file name and parameter, please know that semantic over-scoring indicates over-optimization. Semantics can very easily indicate unnatural usage of language. So do not get carried away. Be natural.

Also please understand that any apparent search term match is simply the last step in a long series of algorithms and filters that only highlights the search terms. Please note that searches can match terms not found on sites and pages. For example, car versus automobile. This is done using ontologies to match search intent.

*So to answer your question, the fact that the term javascript appears within the domain name and path is perfectly fine and normal. In fact, it is optimal.*

I wrote more in this answer: [Why would a website with keyword stuffing rank higher than one without in google search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81551/why-would-a-website-with-keyword-stuffing-rank-higher-than-one-without-in-google/81552#81552)

Answer (score 1):

1. The fewer the parameters in your dynamic URL, the better. One or two
   parameters is much better than seven or eight. Avoid
   superfluous/nonessential parameters like tracking codes.
2. A static looking URL (containing no ampersands, equals signs, or question
   marks) is more search optimal than a dynamic one.
3. Having keywords in the URL is more optimal than no keywords.
4. A keyword in the filename
   portion of the URL is more beneficial than in a
   directory/subdirectory name.