# How to exclude keywords from appearing in keyword density checks?

Tags: seo, keywords

I have small blog and when I count the density of keywords in that, unexpectedly keywords like "comments", "share", and "admin" comes up as keywords, which I don't want.

How can I exclude keywords from appearing in keyword density counts?

Comment: Keyword density is a myth. For Google, it always was. Google does not match keywords. Never has. The proof is in the original research paper and design of Google. Any SEO that touts density should not be listened to. Here is one answer that will help: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81551/why-would-a-website-with-keyword-stuffing-rank-higher-than-one-without-in-google/81552#81552

Comment: I agree with closetnoc.   There is no reason to measure keyword density for SEO.   Google does not use it as a ranking signal.   If you look at which pages rank in Google, they have keyword densities all over the map.

Answer (score 2):

You can't exclude keywords from appearing in keyword density counts by editing your website's code.

Depending on the software you're using to do the keyword density check, you may have an option to blacklist words so they aren't counted on the keyword density report.

On a side note, if you're planning to rank your website on major search engines like Google, Bing, Yahoo, Yandex, etc., you will probably don't face any issues.

As closetnoc said before, Google and other major search engines doesn't use keyword density as a ranking factor, instead they use something called Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA). On this topic, I can recommend 2 readings for you:

1. https://moz.com/blog/lda-and-googles-rankings-well-correlated
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis

Comment: +1 for mentioning semantics. I have been talking about semantics in search for quite some time. The MOZ article is as good as any, however, there are some technological errors as I recall. What is important is that people get the idea of how search works and stop following really really really bad SEO advice. Cheers!!