# SEO - Keyword in all headings | penalty?

Tags: seo, google-search, penalty, heading

I am wondering if the following structure would result in a penalty due to the fact that all headings have the keyword in them and as the first word of each heading.

H1 - Brake Repair in City State

H2 - Brake Repair Services

H3 - Brake Pad Replacement

H3 - Brake Fluid Change

H3 - Brake Inspection

H3 - Are your car brakes making noise?

H3 - Is your brake fluid low in the reservoir?

H2 - How Brakes Work

I do not want to get penalized for including "Brake / Brakes" too many times

Comment: Search is NOT about keywords. Create a site for users please.

Comment: @closetnoc Would you say that the above structure would be bad for users?

Comment: Your questions are about keywords and it appears that you are too focused on keywords. Search is not about keywords. Write naturally and write for users. Keep it that simple.

Comment: While not answering your question directly, this answer may help you understand things a bit. Cheers!! https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81551/why-would-a-website-with-keyword-stuffing-rank-higher-than-one-without-in-google/81552#81552

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One line answer: Do not think too much about keywords vs heading tags. Create content which will be useful for the user.

**Meaning:**

You can have h1, few h2 and so on. But don't think too much as you need to place keywords in each. Try to have generic headings which may or may not include keywords in each.

Instead of worrying about keywords and heading tags too much create useful content by having appropriate text, bullet points, images, videos (Very useful in above industry).

If you will have useful content it will rank well rather than stuffing keywords in each heading.

**Example:**

Let's say you have got 2 main keywords for the page and few secondary keywords then you may follow following approach:

H1: Your main keywords, and then have rich content under this.

h2: Your secondary keywords with few extra words, again have rich content.

h2, h3 etc: Keep it generic.

Focus more on actual content which will be the point of difference. Quality content can rank well regardless.

Comment: If it were a natural flow to organize the content, do you think it would still result in a penalty?

Comment: Google doesn't expect you to produce top end editorial content, so i would say, just don't worry and just produce good quality content, make sure it is not too short, a service page with 600+ words should be good enough. Generally, if your content is poor it may not rank well. Having keywords etc in headings etc, all good. Don't stress there will be no penalty for natural content flow.