# The name of a month as a string vs digit in a URL -- any downsides for SEO?

Tags: url, url-parameters, clean-urls

I'm aware about the difference between my_domain.com/my-article1-title and my_domain.com/2015/12/my-article1-title. In my application I have the following type of urls: my_domain.com/2015/december/my-article1-title

Since the month is a word, not a digit, is there any downside for SEO? Will it be treated as a keyword and thus will be confused with the title of an article? Or is a search engine smart enough to realize that "december" is a part of a date?

Comment: You are seriously over thinking this. The short answer is No. Ontologies understand that 12 is December.

Comment: @closetnoc the question is whether a search engine is able to do so

Comment: Yes. Of course. Ontologies are used to understand meaning. Ontologies know 12, Dec, December, etc. So is there an issue with SEO? The answer is No. Both are the same. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc  the question is whether a search engine is able to do so

Comment: Google use only those keywords which is matched with user query, rest of keywords, google does not care. If someone type 12 on their query then first URL will be great, and if someone type december on their query then second URL will be great. Google does not confuse here, yes google consider it as dates, but they also consider it as keywords as well.

Comment: Yes. It will. Halfway down in this answer, I explain ontologies and how search engines use them. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81551/why-would-a-website-with-keyword-stuffing-rank-higher-than-one-without-in-google/81552#81552 Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the digits, as it makes your url shorter and easier to read for your users.

Comment: How is this answer helpful beyond what had already said by other users?

Comment: added the user's perspective to the discussion. It's not really important if Google understands it as december or not. I would use the short version because of a better user experience > easier to read the url.